# ¿Como enviar un valor a una TempData desde js/jquery o ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, razor

Tengo una View que muestra la descripción del producto con un botón Agregar a carrito. Cuando el cliente pulse el botón , necesito enviarle a la `Tempdata["ProductsAddedToShoppingCar"]` con una funcion js el valor de 1, si posteriormente quiere agregar otro producto, el valor de la Tempdata tiene que cambiar a 2 y así sucesivamente por cada producto que vaya agregando. ¿Cómo se hace para enviar a traves de javascript el valor a la Tempdata?

Aca el controller donde creo la Tempdata

```html
public ActionResult index()
        {
            List<LightBook> list = new List<LightBook>();
            LightBookService lbs = new LightBookService();
            //Guardo en la ViewBag.User el nombre del usuario guardado en TempData
            ViewBag.User = "";

            if (TempData["User"] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.User = TempData["User"];
            }
         
            //Obteniendo todos los libros de la db
            list = lbs.getListLightBooks();
            
            //ACA LA TEMPDATA
            TempData["ProductsAddedToShoppingCar"] = 0;
            return View(list);

        }
```

Aca la view con el botón agregar al carrito

```html
@model Librery_MVC.Models.Libro
@using Librery_MVC.Models
@using Librery_MVC.Services

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UsserLayout.cshtml";
    Autor autor = new Autor();
    Categoria category = new Categoria();
    Editorial editorial = new Editorial();
    AutorService sa = new AutorService();
    EditorialService es = new EditorialService();
    CategoriaService cs = new CategoriaService();

    autor = sa.getAutor(Model.IdAutor);
    category = cs.getCategoria(Model.IdCategoria);
    editorial = es.GetEditorial(Model.IdEditorial);

}

<div class="row" id="div-row">

    <div class="col-md-4 contImgBook">

        <img src="/@Model.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" />       
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-volver" href="@Url.Action("index", "Usser")">Volver</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 contInfo">

        <h2 class="text-center">@Model.Nombre</h2><br />
        <p>@Model.Descripcion</p>
        <label for="autor">Autor:</label>
        <span>@autor.Nombre</span><br />
        <label for="categoria">Categoria:</label>
        <span>@category.Nombre</span><br />
        <label for="editorial">Editorial:</label>
        <span>@editorial.Nombre</span><br />
        <label for="precio">Precio:</label>
        <span>$ @Model.Precio</span><br />
        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad disponible:</label>
        <span>@Model.Cantidad</span><br />
        <hr />
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="addToShoppingCar();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" id="glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>AGREGAR AL CARRITO</button>

    </div>


</div>
```

Y aca en el navbar mostraría el valor de la Tempdata

```html
@{
    TempData.Keep("User");
    TempData.Keep("ProductsAddedToShoppingCar");
 }

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse fade-in" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            //ACA MUESTRO EL VALOR DE LA TEMPDATA
                <li>@TempData["ProductsAddedToShoppingCar"</li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Saludos. Coloca el valor de ese `@TempData` en un elemento conocido; el cual puedas extraer su valor. Como tal (si mal no recuerdo) no existe el lado del cliente.

Comment: gracias por responder! a elemento conocido te refieres a etiqueta? porque de serlo así, el valor de la Tempdata esta en un <li>.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Sí, o puede ser un `input` oculto; sin importar que elemento elijas para ello el caso es que puedas obtener su valor; lo que implica debes saber como se llama o referirlo para ello inequivocamente.

Comment: yo quisiera hacer algo como esto desde js, y no se si se puede:

Comment: var valor = x;          TempData["ProductsAddedToShoppingCar"].val(x);

Comment: Te sugiero desde el buscador web de tu preferencia usar como criterio **TempData tiempo de vida** o **TempData ciclo de vida**. Suerte.